# MySQL return N rows based on date interval

Tags: mysql

I need create a query to return N rows based in an date interval. It's simple but i don't can be :/

The base query:

```
SELECT
  f.many_fields
FROM
  tb_foo f
WHERE
  f.id_foo = 14
```

This query returns 1 row based on my ID.
But, I've date interval like '2012-10-10' at '2012-10-30' to apply on this query and at end the base query will be return 20 rows based on diff of date interval.

Can be possible make this ?

```
SELECT
  f.many_fields,
  bar.*
FROM
  tb_foo f,
  (SELECT x FROM dual limit DATEDIFF('2012-10-10','2012-10-30')) bar
WHERE
  f.id_foo = 14
```

Real query:

```
SELECT
  m.id_matricula,
  a.nome
FROM
  tb_matricula m
    inner join tb_aluno a on (a.id_aluno = m.id_matricula)
WHERE
  m.id_matricula = 14
```

Start date = 2012-10-10
End date = 2012-10-30

I'll use this result on iReport to build an grid with num of rows based on difference between of this dates.

Example founded on Google searches:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( dt.d ,'-' ,days.d ) AS dates
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) AS d
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    '0' AS a1
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '1'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '2'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '3'
            ) a JOIN(
                SELECT
                    '0' AS b1
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '1'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '2'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '3'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '4'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '5'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '6'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '7'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '8'
            UNION ALL SELECT
                    '9'
            ) b
        WHERE
            CONVERT(
                CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) ,
                UNSIGNED
            ) <=(
                SELECT
                    DAY(
                        CONCAT( '2012-10' ,'-01' ) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                    )
            )
            AND CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) <> '00'
    ) days JOIN(
        SELECT
            '2012-10' AS d
    ) dt
 HAVING
    dates BETWEEN '2012-10-02' AND '2012-10-05'
ORDER BY
    dates
;
```

Comment: When you say date interval, do you mean between two specific dates?  What is your desired result set?  Add an example of what your ideal output will be.

Comment: what's the significance of `f.id_foo = 14` when you are actually looking for records between two dates? Or are there many records for that one id value?

Comment: Hi nawfal, indeed the date it's not related with tables of from clause, i just want duplicate the result based on difference between these dates.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an solution to this. Using a sub-query i can return many rows based on date interval, that, don't have any relation with main query. So i have this:

```
SELECT
    datas. * ,
    m.id_matricula ,
    p.nome
FROM
    tb_matricula m INNER JOIN tb_aluno a
        ON(
        a.id_aluno = m.id_aluno
    ) INNER JOIN tb_perfil p
        ON(
        p.id_perfil = a.id_perfil
    ) ,
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT( dt.d ,'-' ,days.d ) AS dates
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) AS d
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            '0' AS a1
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '1'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '2'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '3'
                    ) a JOIN(
                        SELECT
                            '0' AS b1
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '1'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '2'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '3'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '4'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '5'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '6'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '7'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '8'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '9'
                    ) b
                WHERE
                    CONVERT(
                        CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) ,
                        UNSIGNED
                    ) <=(
                        SELECT
                            DAY(
                                CONCAT( '2012-02' ,'-01' ) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                            )
                    )
                    AND CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) <> '00'
            ) days JOIN(
                SELECT
                    '2012-02' AS d
            ) dt
    UNION ALL SELECT
            CONCAT( dt.d ,'-' ,days.d ) AS dates
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) AS d
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            '0' AS a1
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '1'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '2'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '3'
                    ) a JOIN(
                        SELECT
                            '0' AS b1
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '1'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '2'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '3'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '4'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '5'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '6'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '7'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '8'
                    UNION ALL SELECT
                            '9'
                    ) b
                WHERE
                    CONVERT(
                        CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) ,
                        UNSIGNED
                    ) <=(
                        SELECT
                            DAY(
                                CONCAT( '2012-03' ,'-01' ) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                            )
                    )
                    AND CONCAT( a1 ,b1 ) <> '00'
            ) days JOIN(
                SELECT
                    '2012-03' AS d
            ) dt
        ORDER BY
            dates
    ) datas
WHERE
    m.id_matricula = 42
    and
    datas.dates BETWEEN '2012-02-25' AND '2012-03-05';
```

Running this statement for ID = 42 and 3 days of date difference i have:

```
DATES,          ID_MATRICULA, NOME
2012-02-25  42        R ANDRE F DOMINGOS
2012-02-26  42        R ANDRE F DOMINGOS
2012-02-27  42        R ANDRE F DOMINGOS
```